# De Bretagne ou de la Bretagne ?

Tags: de

I have come across references to 'les quatre coins de la Bretagne' and 'les falaises de Bretagne'. It seems more usual not to use the definite article in such a situation, but is there a grammatical principle involved ?

Answer (score 4):

*Aux quatre coins **de** Bretagne* is also possible but the form with *la* is more common.  The phrase is about the region as a proper noun:

> In every corner of Brittany

I don't think "In every Brittany corner" (or "in every Breton corner") would work.

In the second phrase, the genitive is closer to an adjective:

> *Les falaises **de** Bretagne* = *Les falaises bretonnes* ("Breton cliffs" should be fine here I guess)

*Les falaises de la Bretagne* isn't incorrect though, but less natural. It would work if it wasn't generic (*Les falaises **de** **la** Bretagne du Nord*)

[image]

Comment: Dans la première phrase, _but the form with le is more common_ --- pourquoi "le" ?

Comment: @Oreste Parce que je me suis trompé... Je voulais bien sûr parler de l'article féminin *la*.